# Different ways to read json data and convert into DataFrame in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What are the different ways to read Json data in Spark and create a Data Frame. One way is:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json("/../../jsonfile")
```

The above command triggers an action which I want to avoid, so trying to find other ways to create a dataframe.

Comment: What is it that you want to avoid?

Comment: val df = sqlContext.read.json("/../../jsonfile") this command read the input data ,  in the subsequent step i select subset data from df  and cache it which again triggers action and reads the input data again , i want to avoid reading the input data twice.

Comment: Can you add the additional code? By using `cache()` you should be able to avoid reading the data twice.